# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm just learning how to use SQLAlchemy. I'm trying to do the following, but storing title and link in two separate tables:

```
temp = Submissions(title=u'Facebook Homepage', link=u'http://facebook.com')
session.add(temp)
session.flush()
transaction.commit()
```

via:

```
class Links(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'links'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = Column(Text)
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now())

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

class Submissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'submissions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column(TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now())
    title = Column(Text)
    link_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('links.id'))
    link = relation(Links)

    def __init__(self, title, link):  
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
```

However, I always get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

What is going on? Is there a better way to code this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't quite do that with `relationship`.

You need to arrange for the `Link` to be looked up in some way.

The most obvious is to just look it up directly.

```
submission_link = session.query(Links) \
                         .filter(Links.link == u'http://facebook.com') \
                         .first()
if submission_link is None:
    submission_link = Links(link=u'http://facebook.com')
    session.add(submission_link)

submission = Submissions(title=u'Facebook Homepage', link=submission_link)
session.add(submission)
session.commit()
```

You can also use [hybrid attributes](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) to get something that looks a bit more like your example, but its substantially more convoluted.

also, it's `relationship`, `relation` is deprecated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `session.add(submission)`?

Answer (score 2):

I would configure the relation as [one-to-one](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=relationship#one-to-one) (`uselist=False`) and add a property which would wrap the `link` relationship. The SA configuration would then look like below and your code should work just fine creating, updating and deleting the link. You might need to configure the relation for have `delete-orphan` option in a `cascade`.

```
...
class Submissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'submissions'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now())
    title = Column(Text)
    link_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('links.id'))
    link_rel = relation(Links, backref=backref("_submission", uselist=False))

    def __init__(self, title, link=None):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link

    @property
    def link(self):
        return self.link_rel and self.link_rel.link

    @link.setter
    def link(self, value):
        if value is None:
            self.link_rel = None
        elif self.link_rel is None:
            self.link_rel = Links(value)
        else:
            self.link_rel.link = value
...
```

Comment: can't upvote, but here's a thanks. unfortunately i'm separating links because the list is onto, not one-to-one.