# Is it possible to scrape data to two different database tables?

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a website data but i want to store it in a database.

My current code is like this:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, callback=self.parse
                            meta={"use_splash": False})

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//li'):
           item = ProjectjomkerjaItem()
           item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/div[@class="position"]/div[@id="job-title-job-listing"]/strong/text()').extract()
           item['company'] = sel.xpath('a/div[@class="position"]/div[@class="company"]/strong/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
           item['job_type'] = sel.xpath('a/ul[@class="meta"]/li/text()').extract()
           for link in item['link']:
             yield scrapy.Request(link, meta={'item': item},
                           callback=self.description)

    def description(self, response):
           sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
           item = response.meta['item']
           item['location'] = sel.xpath('//h2[@class="page-subtitle"]/span[@class="job-location"]/text()').extract()
           item['salary'] = sel.xpath('//h2[@class="page-subtitle"]/span[@class="company-social-title"]/text()').extract()
           item['job_description'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="job-desc"]/div[@class="show-more-inner"]/span[@class="no_translate"]/ul/li/text()').extract()
          item['more_job_description'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="job-desc"]/div[@class="show-more-inner"]/span[@class="no_translate"]/p/text()').extract()
           item['others'] = sel.xpath('//div/span[@class="no_translate"]/text()').extract()
           item['about_company'] = sel.xpath('//div/span[@class="no_translate"]/span[@id="job_detail_"]/text()').extract()
           yield item
```

Some items like "about_company" and "company" will belong to a table2 and the rest on another table1. Table2 will have a job_id which is the unique ID of table1.

How do i achieve this?

(PS - I am using postgresql with sqlalchemy.

**EDIT:**
This is another try i did in pipelines.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import Jobs, db_connect, create_jobs_table
from models import CompanyDetails, db_connect, create_company_details_table
from projectjomkerja.items import ProjectjomkerjaMainItem
from projectjomkerja.items import ProjectjomkerjaSecondaryItem

class ProjectjomkerjaPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates deals table.
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_jobs_table(engine)
        create_company_details_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       if isinstance(item, ProjectjomkerjaMainItem):
         session = self.Session()
         jobs = Jobs(**item)

         try:
            session.add(jobs)
            session.commit()
         except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
         finally:
            session.close()

         return item

       if isinstance(item, ProjectjomkerjaSecondaryItem):
          session = self.Session()
          company_details = CompanyDetails(**item)

          try:
             session.add(company_details)
             session.commit()
          except:
             session.rollback()
             raise
          finally:
             session.close()

          return item

    def process_item2(self, item, spider):
       item1 = item
       item2 = item1['item2']
       job_id = Jobs(item1)
       CompanyDetails(item2, job_id)
```

Still, i did not get my job_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to this in scrapy pipelines.
You cancreate 2 item classes, one for each table. 
In pipeline, you check for the item type, based on that you store it in the table you want.
From your description, the code can look like this:

```
class Item1(Item):
    location = Field()
    salary = Field()
    job_description = Field()
    more_job_description = Field()
    others = Field()
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    job_type = Field()

class Item2(Item):
    company = Field()
    about_company = Field()


class SQLAlchemyPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, Item1):
            save_in_table1
        if isinstance(item, Item2):
            save_in_table2

    def process_item2(self, item, spider):
        item1 = item
        item2 = item1['item2']
        job_id = save_in_table1(item1)
        save_in_table2(item2, job_id)
```

Comment: Does this require me to use many if-statements since i have a lot of items. How do i group items into each if statements? is Item1 something like item['location'], etc?

Comment: can you be more explicit with your comment?

Comment: I was confused with Item1 and Item2. Thank you for explaining to me about it which is actually the grouping of the items in items.py

Comment: from parse method, you can yield both item types in meta={'item1':item1, 'item2':item2}. In description callback you can  append all items in a list, than using a for, you will yield all items in the list.  The pipeline, will decide what item, based on its type, will go in what table.  I hope is clear :)

Comment: I come back again, because I think that this solution will not solve the relation (job_id FK) that you need to achieve, between this 2 items. If you solve that, please let us know how, but I am afraid that you need to embed both items in one, in order to have a relation between them.

Comment: Yes. It would not solve the job_id foreign key for the database but i think i would have to look deeper into SQLAlchemy to get the ID of the table with the primary key (table for Item1) for each new record created and then insert new records for table for Item2 which includes the job_id of Item1 table. Also, i think i would need to have the "created_at" and "updated_at" data when using SQLAlchemy because my app checks the date and time of each record.

Comment: Well, in this current solution, I think there is no way to have a relation between these 2 items, they are independent on each other.  Better is to embed item2 in item1, than in pipeline, you will receive both items in one and you will save both at the same time and you will be able to create a relation. see my update.

Comment: I got a question. What do you mean save_in_table1 and save_in_table2? I tried to follow http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-4/ and i am almost there. (i am saving the data in postgresql)

Comment: I mean to save the first item, as described in the post you follow. When the item is saved in db, you will have a job id. Forward you will save the item2 in db and use the job id from the first item, to make a foreign key relation.

Comment: I have tried it (updated on my question above) but i still did not have job_id in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, however you need to define the tables in a models.py file.

You should have the ForeignKey relationship on the models.py file.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296296/attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-sa-instance-state#) provides an excellent way to handle the relationship between the 2 tables